# C++ Primer exercise 1.12 results puzzleing

Tags: c++, visual-c++

EXERCISE 1.12: What does the following "for" loop do? what is the final value of sum?

The code that applies to the above exercise is:

```
#include < iostream >

int main()    
{    
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = -100; i <= 100; ++i)
        sum += i;

    std::cout << "sum of i is : " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

The result of `sum` or `i` is `0`.

My question is with the condition of `i <= 100`. how is the answer `0`?

I would think the program would count from `-100` all the way up to `100`.

Comment: `i <= 100` evaluates true if less than **or equal to**. The looped over values  include the value 100.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed it counts all the way from `-100` to `100` inclusive. Let's make a shorter example (-2 to <=2):

```
sum = -2 + -1 + 0 + 1 + 2 = 0
```

do you see it now?

Comment: Technically it's not counting, it's summing. Counting would be `sum++`. Maybe that's what op expected.

Comment: @luk32 - it does both. It counts (in `i`) and sums (in `sum`).

Comment: No, it is not counting. How starts counting from `-100`? It is iterating in `i`. Not counting.

Comment: OOOOO!!!! so just to ensure I am getting it correctly, when "i" is set to -100, then it is checked against the condition, if the condition is true, then the code "++i" can also be written as -100 + -99 ...etc all the way to a positive 100 which of course equals zero?

Comment: Well, maybe I actually tried apply the mathematical sense too strictly.

Comment: @user3089453 - yes, that's basically what happens. The `for` loop "iterates" over the values of `i`, starting at `-100`, incrementing by `1` each time, until (last time) it gets all the way to `+100`. And the sum of all those numbers is zero. A total of 201 passes through the loop.

Comment: @luk32 - I see your point but yes, it is perhaps a bit strict given the question we're addressing here.

Comment: @Floris, I would add the word inclusive to the end of the first sentence. So often in program saying "from a to b" means inclusive of a and exclusive of b, unlike in this instance.

Comment: @floris, if i am reading the ++i code correctly it translates into "i = i + 1 < -100 = -100 + 1 < -100 = -99" where in the code is the program told to add -100 and -99? hope i am not confusing.

Comment: @user3089453 - not quite. The way the for loop works: Initialize (set `i=-100;`), Test (`i<=100` is `true`), perform loop (`sum+=i;`), perform update (`++i`), test, loop, update, … So you start summing with `i = -100;` and the last term is `i = 100;`. And the sum is zero.

Comment: @Floris, ahhh ok. i got it now. i was unaware that the (sum += i;) portion of the code was part of the (for) loop. i thought all computation was contained in the for statements condition portion.

so more visual way of putting the code would be :

for 
(
int i = -100; 
i <= 100; 
sum += i;
++i;
)

Comment: `for ( int i = -100; i <= 100; sum += i++ ) ;` but, thats still bad code, the doing part is supposed ot be outside if you want other people to read it.

Comment: @user3089453 almost. You could write `for(int i = -100; sum+=i, i < 100; ++i)` but that is VERY tricky. I use the "comma operator" which allows the `sum+=i` to be evaluated BEFORE the comparison (which is why I use `<` instead of `<=`). **Really not recommended if you are looking for clarity.** Learn to love the braces `{}` for the `for` loop!

Answer (score 1):

It adds all of the numbers from -100 to 100. Since 100-100+99-99+...1-1+0=0, the total is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(<init> ; <test>; <update>) { X;Y;Z; }
```

loosely translates to

```
 <init>;  while (<test>) { X;Y;Z; <update>; }
```

We use for loops instead of while loops because its often nice to have all the looping logic in one chunk, then all the per-loop doing logic within the braces, where as a while loop can make them a little tougher to separate cognitively.